# Error While decoding ! The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters

Tags: c#, base64

Error :- Error While decoding !  "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Encoded string :-

```
string decode = "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";
```

Calling DecryptString method:-

```
 string decrypted = DecryptString(decode, key, iv);
```

DecryptString Method Logic:-

```
public string DecryptString(string cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Instantiate a new Aes object to perform string symmetric encryption
            Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();

            encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            //encryptor.KeySize = 256;
            //encryptor.BlockSize = 128;
            //encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Set key and IV
            encryptor.Key = key;
            encryptor.IV = iv;

            // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            // Instantiate a new encryptor from our Aes object
            ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = encryptor.CreateDecryptor();

            // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
            // memory stream
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // Will contain decrypted plaintext
            string plainText = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                

                // Convert the ciphertext string into a byte array
           byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);  //getting Padding error 

                // Decrypt the input ciphertext string
                cryptoStream.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

                // Complete the decryption process
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                // Convert the decrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
                byte[] plainBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

                // Convert the decrypted byte array to string
                plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }

            // Return the decrypted data as a string
            return plainText;
        }
```

In the above example while I'm converting the encrypt string to decrypt string I'm getting the padding error

Give me your best suggestion to achieve this without error.

I'm new to this kind of decrypt logic's.

Comment: Please read [mre]. Do you still experience the problem if you try the `Convert.FromBase64String` call by itself? Then the rest is not relevant to the problem. As for the problem, I don't understand why there is a question. The error message told you, very explicitly, that the problem is that *the data is wrong*. It suggested some things that could be wrong with the data. Did you try to check for those? For example, did you try to check the process that creates the data? Did you try to check if you can make it work with shorter data?

Comment: The encoded string example isn't even valid C# code, making it really hard to help you.

Comment: your base64 input contains '\'  , that's not a valid base64 character.

Comment: @jps https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411305/is-it-possible-to-have-a-backslash-by-itself-in-preformatted-text-how :) (but in this case, I really think it's easier to just say "a backslash"...)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and I have just removed the "\" in code and changed the two lines of code "var cipher = new byte[fullCipher.Length - iv.Length];" & System.Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, cipher.Length); in decrypt method logic it is working fine now